# SQL Query to create date difference from current date

Tags: sql, postgresql, lag, date-arithmetic, lead

| subscription_id | purchase_date | current_date | plan_end_date | date_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 01-04-2022 | 11-04-2022 | 14-04-2022 | 3 |
| 2222 | 02-04-2022 | 11-04-2022 | 09-04-2022 | -2 |
| 3333 | 06-04-2022 | 11-04-2022 | 11-04-2022 | 0 |

I am looking for the above answer but not getting.
It's coming different answer if I use lag and lead function.

```
CASE
        WHEN plan_end_date > cur_date THEN cur_date - LAG(plan_end_date) OVER (ORDER BY cur_date) 
        WHEN plan_end_date < cur_date THEN cur_date - LEAD(plan_end_date) OVER (ORDER BY cur_date)
        WHEN plan_end_date = cur_date THEN NULL
    END AS date_diff
```

here is the above condition I have used.

Comment: `ORDER BY cur_date`, and cur_date seems to have always the same value?  Maybe change it to `ORDER BY cur_date,plan_end_date` ?  to sort on plan_end_date when cur_date has same value

Comment: @Luuk The answer is still wrong.

Comment: Can you provide more date? I created a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=263dbc7b7e59b580bbce9bdd8ea0b149) and there is not enough data to reproduce your problem.

Comment: What are you trying to do with lead and lag? What is your original data, what is the exact problem?

Comment: `SELECT cast(plan_end_date as date) -cast(cur_date as date)` , should be giving you the days difference.

Comment: I don't get the impression you really want to look outside the current row. There's no need for `lead/lag()` if so.

Comment: I need for 7 days date difference which gives today's date and +3 as well as -3 days. So I can pick any date as today's date to get both sides of the day over day cycle.

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT cast(plan_end_date as date) -cast(cur_date as date)` , should be giving you the difference in days.